# Laravel Email Set Multiple Template (eg. Change Password Template, Details Order Template, New User Notification Template)

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-8, laravel-mail

Currently, I know Laravel has shipped mail templates. but only one template. How to create other templates and tell which template need to use before sending an email.

```
public function send_email_package()
{
$details=[
    'greeting' => 'Testing Rental Package',
    'body' => 'Thank You, You Recieve Package A',
    'actiontext' => 'Check Status',
    'actionurl' => '#',
    'lastline' => 'Collect Package at Branch A',
];


Notification::route('mail', 'example_01@gmail.com')
    ->route('mail', 'example_01@zmikusel.com')
    ->notify(new RentalPackageProcessing($details));

dd('email-sended');
}
```

> In here how to specify which template need I use.

Example like this

1. send_email_package()->use_template_package_a
2. send_change_password()->use_template_package_b
3. send_notification_blabla()->use_template_package_d

Answer (score 1):

You can create multiple templates to send emails. The best way to do it is:

1. Create a folder called 'emails': 'resources > views > emails'.
2. Create an email template: You can use litmus, a free site for templates of all kinds https://litmus.com/community/templates.
3. Within the template you can place the variables that need to be displayed in the email, in your case the $details variable.
4. Execute command php artisan make:mail RentalEmail , so that a configuration file is created and you can pass the data you need to send, located in "App\Mail\RentEmail"
5. In the RentEmail file, put the data that you will accept in the constructor, to be called in the `build().` method
   Ex:

   ```
    protected $x;
    protected $y;
    public function __construct($x, $y){
             $this->x= $x;
             $this->y= $y;
         }
    public function build()
        {
            return $this->from('email@email.com')
              ->subject('Notification 1')
              ->view('emails.template1')
              ->with([
                'id' => $this->x->x,
                'email' => $this->y,
                ])
            ;
        }
   ```
6. Then you can call the RentMail class, like this:

   `Mail::to($user->email)->send(new RentMail($x, $y->email));`
7. To make it dynamic in a single class, you can pass a variable as a parameter to use the template you want. Ex (`->view($xTemplate)`)